# Receive a String in this format: "1-10" and create an array with the amount of numbers in the range

Tags: javascript, vcenter

How to Receive a String in this format: "1-10" and create an array with the amount of numbers in the range. Print the array to screen using a for loop.

I.E - "1-5" received so they array will be: {1,2,3,4,5}

create for workflow with vCenter orchestrator.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code in a [mcve]

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: @avner FYI, by convention we annotate arrays using square brackets (e.g., `[1,2,3,4,5]`), reserving curly braces for objects and hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = "1-10";  //SAMPE INPUT DATA.
var foo = input.split("-");  //PASRING INPUT DATA.
var answer = []; 
for(var i = foo[0]; i<= foo[1]; i++){
   answer.push(parseInt(i));  //MAKE AN ARRAY.
}
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers, say *what* you did, and *why*. Nor is it useful to give the OP a fish rather than teaching him/her to fish.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm so sorry. Actually, I'm not good teacher, and I'm not good at English. If I explain how to make some algorithm, I may have to spend all my time. I just want to help someone.

Comment: It's working, thanks!

Comment: @AvnerVidal It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the string into `array` and then iterate in a loop to get the iteration.

```js
let str = "1-5";
str = str.split('-');
for(let i = parseInt(str[0]); i<=parseInt(str[1]); i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Your loop will be more efficient if you parse the end number first, instead of each time you check the bounds.

Comment: Yes sure.. Should leave some things for the person asking the questions to. But yes doing it first will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You may use some cool ES6:

```
Array.range = function(s){
 const [start,end] = s.split("-");
 return Array.from({length:start-end}).map((_,i)=>i+ +start);
};
```

Usable like this:

```
Array.range("1-10") //[1,2,3...]
```